# Tablix with data values below each other

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to build a Table with the data values below each other.

Using the usual SSRS wizard, the data values are shown next to each other, making each data column wide.

Example:

Product...........1 Apr......2 Apr....3 Apr.....4 Apr

Prod 1

```
   Count    10    12  14    9

   Cost     3     5   6     3

   Total    30    30  84    27
```

Prod 2

```
   Count    10    12  14    9

   Cost     3     5   6     3

   Total    30    30  84    27
```

I managed to do this manually, by adding rows under the Product group, and manually inserting the fields.
But I still need to add these into the totals columns.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Query:

> SELECT
>
> [Date]
>
> ,product_name
>
> ,COUNT(DISTINCT saleID) AS [Count Distinct_saleID]
>
> ,SUM(cost) AS Cost
>
> FROM
>
> SalesHistory
>
> WHERE
>
> [Date] >= @Date
>
> AND [Date] <= @Date2
>
> GROUP BY
>
> ,[Date]
>
> ,product_name

Comment: Can you please share the data returning by your dataset, so we can see how your data structure looks like?

Comment: I added the query to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case Matrix is more appropriate control than a Table.

1.Add a Matrix to your report:

[image: 1]

2.Select [Date] as a columns source:

[image: 2]

3.In the right bottom area of the Design tab you will find Column Groups pane, right click on the existing group then Add Total -> After:

[image: 3]

4.After some manipulations your report in design mode will look like following:

[image: 4]

5.And eventualy in the preview mode:

[image: 5]

Hope it helps.